# How can I bind complex type annotations to an alias?

Tags: python, flask, mypy

I'm using mypy and Python 3.8 and am wondering if there's a way to bind a complex type annotation, like `flask.testing.FlaskClient[flask.Response]` to a type alias?

It seems like I can do this and make mypy happy, but doing so will actually cause things to blow up when the code is run.

For example:

```
import flask
import flask.testing

TestClient = flask.testing.FlaskClient[flask.Response]
```

This is a problem because `FlaskClient` is not subscriptable of course.

Comment: See if a string annotation `TestClient = "flask.testing.FlaskClient[flask.Response]"` helps. Python's type hints are such a weird mess.

Comment: I had hoped that would work too, but instead the type checker will complain that the e.g. return type doesn't match "TestClient"--very annoying.